# How to set pthread name at the time of creation?

Tags: linux, pthreads

I am using pthread in my program. For creation using pthread_create(). Right after creation I am using pthread_setname_np() to set the created thread's name.

I am observing that the name I set takes a small time to reflect, initially the thread inherits the program name.

Any suggestions how I can set the thread name at the time I create the thread using pthread_create()? I researched a bit in the available pthread_attr() but did not find a function that helps.

A quick way to reproduce what I am observing, is as follows:

```
void * thread_loop_func(void *arg) {
   // some code goes here
   
   pthread_getname_np(pthread_self(), thread_name, sizeof(thread_name));
   // Output to console the thread_name here
   
   // some more code
}

int main() {
   // some code
   pthread_t test_thread;
   pthread_create(&test_thread, &attr, thread_loop_func, &arg);
   pthread_setname_np(test_thread, "THREAD-FOO");
   // some more code, rest of pthread_join etc follows.
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
<program_name>
<program_name>
THREAD-FOO
THREAD-FOO
....
```

I am looking for the first console output to reflect THREAD-FOO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how I can set the thread name at the time I create the thread using pthread_create()?

That is not possible. Instead you can use a barrier or mutex to synchronize the child thread until it's ready to be run. Or you can set the thread name from inside the thread (if any other threads are not using it's name).

Do not to use `pthread_setname_np`. This is a nonstandard GNU extension. The `_np` suffix literally means "non-portable". Write portable code and instead use your own place where you store your thread names.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of [`pthread_setname_np(3)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setname_np.3.html) you can use [`prctl(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/prctl.2.html) with `PR_SET_NAME`. The only limitation with this function is that you can only set the name of the calling process/thread. But since your example is doing exactly that, there should be no problem with this solution AND it's a portable standard API.

Comment: Worth noting also that `pthread_setname_np` and `prctl` behave differently in the face of the name argument exceeding 16 bytes. `pthread_setname_np` will just fail, whereas `prctl` would silently truncate the name to the allowed length. Depending on the usecase, you may want one or another behavior.